# How to select rows which satisfy subset?

Tags: sql

I want to select items from `tblAOItems` only if `tblAOItemRequirements` contains **at least** rows with specified values eg in this case it must contain rows with attributes 113,148,167

```
SELECT  tblAOItems.name 
FROM tblAOItems
JOIN tblAOItemRequirements ON tblAOItemRequirements.aoid = tblAOItems.aoid
GROUP BY tblAOItems.aoid 
HAVING tblAOItemRequirements.attribute == 113
   AND tblAOItemRequirements.attribute == 148 
   AND tblAOItemRequirements.attribute == 167
```

tblAOItemRequirements:

```
aoid,sequence,type,attribute,value,operator,op_modifier
124014,0,8,113,791,2,0
124014,1,8,148,593,2,4
124014,2,8,167,712,2,4
124014,3,8,151,396,2,4
```

tblAOItems:

```
aoid,name
124014,Ronda
```

Comment: Can the attributes show more than once per each aoid?

Comment: Since you're checking against columns directly (not an **aggregate** of a column), these conditions should be in a  `WHERE` clause - not `HAVING` (which is designed / intended for aggregate conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each attribute can only show once for each `aoid` then you can count the matching rows and check the count is equal to three.

For example:

```
SELECT
  i.aoid,
  max(i.name) as name
from tblAOItems i
JOIN tblAOItemRequirements r on r.aoid = i.aoid
WHERE r.attribute in (113, 148, 167)
GROUP BY i.aoid 
HAVING count(*) = 3
```

If the attributes can show up more than once per `oaid` then subqueries can do the job in the `WHERE` clause.